# How do I get the full path of a copied file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, path, ruby-on-rails-5, cp

I’m using Rails 5.  How do I get the full path of the destination file after copying a file?  I’m currently doing this

```
FileUtils.cp(file_path, dest_dir)
```

Unfortunately the result of this call is nil.  Is there a call that will tell me the full destination path or something else I can do to get this destination path in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

`FileUtils` is a [stdlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) in Ruby. If I understood correctly, what you're trying to do is get the pathname for the file you copied.

You can try this, with Rails, where `dest_dir` is a path:

```
Rails.root.join(dest_dir)
```

Comment: I want the full path of the destination file.  This only gives the destination directory.

Comment: You could use then `Rails.root.join(dest_dir, file_path)`, like @rails-fan showed below.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something off, taht answer is wrong and what you ahve doesn't even return a string, it returns some other kind of object.  Running what you have in the comments returns "#<Pathname:/Users/nataliab/myfile.txt>".  Does it return the correct path for you or were you just guessing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with:

```
filename=File.basename("file/some/where/filename.txt")
 => "filename.txt"

File.join("/dest/dir", filename)
 => "/dest/dir/filename.txt"
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  From my question, if dest_dir = "/tmp" and file_path = "/Users/nataliab/myfile.txt", running FileUtils.cp(file_path, dest_dir), results in "/tmp/Users/nataliab/myfile.txt," which is a file that doesn't exist after the copy operation.

Comment: I suspect there is more going on there beside getting the path. cp does not create non-existing folders for you. You would need to use FileUtils.mkdir_p on the full path first which creates all the missing folders. Given you can write /tmp.

Comment: In my question, you can assume "dest_dir" exists.  I'm trying to get the full path fo the file after it is copied to "dest_dir", using Ruby/Rails.  Does that make sense?  I'm fairly new and I think people don't understand what I'm asking.

Comment: I think I understand what you need now. You should use a real example to make more obvious though.
You need to use File.basename(file_path) to get the filename from the path. Then you can use File.join to join the filename to the destination folder.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if that was the answer you were looking for.